# Express $\frac{\sin 3a}{\sin a}$ with only $\cos a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, parametric

How can I express
$\dfrac{\sin 3a}{\sin a}$ while using only $\cos a$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $$\sin 3a=\sin(2a+a)= \ldots = 3\sin a - 4\sin^3 a$$

So $$\frac{\sin 3a}{\sin a}=3-4\sin^2a=3-4+4\cos^2 a=4\cos ^2a-1$$

Comment: Thank you very much (: is there any formula for the case cos(ka) ?

Comment: @tanto30 There is no formula in general.. But you can derive it using the formulae for the elementary angles.

Comment: @tanto30 You might want to look at [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html).

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sin3a=\sin(2a+a)=\sin2a\cos a+\cos2a\sin a
=2\sin a\cos^2a+(\cos^2a-\sin^2a)\sin a
$$

Can you go on?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sin3a}{\sin a}=\frac{3\sin a-4\sin^3a}{\sin a}$$
$$=3-4\sin^2a$$
$$=3-4(1-\cos^2a)$$
$$=3-4+4\cos^2a$$
$$=4\cos^2a-1$$

Comment: You can use `\sin` and `\cos` in order to *actually* write circular functions (compare $\sin \theta$ with $sin \theta $).

Answer (score 0):

Without expanding $3a$, multiply top and bottom by $2\cos a$:
$$\dfrac{2\sin 3a\cdot \cos a}{2\sin a \cdot \cos a}=\dfrac{\sin (3a+a)+\sin (3a-a)}{\sin 2a}=2\cos 2a+1=2(2\cos^2 a-1)+1=\\
4\cos^2a-1.$$